# If statement String trouble

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to create a program which takes user input of two words and determines whether or not these words are the same.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class L7E3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );
        String word1, word2;

        System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
        word1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
        word2 = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (word1 == word2) {
            System.out.println("The words are " + word1 + " and " + word2 + ". These words are the same.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The words are " + word1 + " and " + word2 + ". These words are not the same.");
        }
    }
}
```

I figured that word1==word2 would have worked to determine whether the two strings were equal, I'm using JGrasp and it goes directly to my else option regardless of input. Am I doing something wrong with strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(word1.equals(word2))
```

`==` doesn't do what you think it does.  `==` essentially compares the memory locations of the two `String` variables and returns `true` only if they're located at the same memory location.  The `String.equals` method compares the contents of the strings and returns `true` if they hold the same characters.

Comment: Ah I had no idea. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JeremyStone Be sure to mark one of the answers as accepted so the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use `String#equals(Object)` instead:

```
word1.equals(word2)
```

For a super detailed explanation to the reasoning why: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/1255746).

Answer (score 0):

For Strings you need to use the `.equals()` function rather than the `==` equality operator.

`if(word1.equals(word2))`

If you wanted to test if two words are the same, while ignoring case ("This" is the same as "this) then you need to do something like this:

`if (word1.toLowerCase().equals(word2.toLowerCase()))`

Also in your specific example you might want to remove unnecesary whitespace from before and after the word ("   word1   " should becomes "word1"). You can do this using the `trim()` function:

`word1 = word.trim();`